# How would I add support for timezone in my application?

Tags: timezone

We're currently storing local datetime of Pacific/Hawaii in the database.  Assuming that I cannot change these dates to UTC, what information do I need to add to support timezone?

My thoughts are:

- First, add a timezone field to indicate which timezone the user is viewing from.  (The user will select this from a dropdown)
- Second, add timezone field to indicate the timezone (Pacific/Hawaii) of the current datetimes values in the database.
- Third, add offset to cover DST hours

So say a user from America/Los_Angeles views the site, it would pull the datetime from the database, append the offset and apply the timezone of Hawaii before converting it to Los Angeles time.  For any calculation or comparison I would convert the Hawaii time to UTC first, then convert the UTC result to Los Angeles.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and without knowing more about your application, the platform, how you use collect dates and times, what they represent, etc., I can only speak in generalities.

- Storing in UTC is recommended, but that is just by convention.  The main necessities are that the time zone you are storing data in does not have DST (which Hawaii hasn't since 1947), and that you do *not* rely on your computer's operating system or environment settings to determine what time zone to use.  You can use the Hawaiian time zone if you must.  Be sure you document it somewhere though!  It will surely be a surprise to anyone else that comes along in the lifecycle of the application.
- While it would wolk, there is absolutely no advantage to doing this.  You could just as easily convert your data to UTC when you roll out these changes and use UTC going forward.  (That would be the preferred approach.)
- The IANA time zone ID for Hawaii is `"Pacific/Honolulu"`.  If you're on Windows/.Net, the `TimeZoneInfo` ID is `"Hawaiian Standard Time"`.  Either way, they must be spelled, cased, and punctuated in exactly that manner.
- Make sure you understand that a Time Zone Offset and a Time Zone are two different concepts.  While Hawaii may use a fixed offset of -10:00, that's not guaranteed for most time zones.  Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) for further details.
- You should probably not attempt to implement your own time zone logic.  There are libraries for this in almost every language.  Look to see what is appropriate for your platform.  (If you provide details, I can offer suggestions.)

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for answering.  Can I hit you up on another scenario?  What if the timezone I'm storing data in has DST, would storing in local datetime still work? 

I should rephrase my question to: does storing the timezone and offset for a local datetime give me enough information to account for DST?  What kind of problems would I run into?

Comment: Also, I should note that I'm storing local datetime of one timezone only.  So if I have a server in Los Angeles, someone visiting from New York would have their input converted from New York local time to Los Angeles local time before storage.

Comment: You would have to store the local time and offset for each and every value.  You can't store the offset separately, as offsets will alternate between standard offset and daylight offset differently for each time zone.  If you want to take this approach, consider using a datatype that's designed for it, such as `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server, or `timestamptz` in Orcale and Postgres.

Comment: Be sure to also read about [daylight saving time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  You should understand that storing a local datetime that might undergo DST changes without also storing an offset will lead to potentially ambiguous data.

Comment: As far as best practices go - your application and the data stored within *should not care* what the time zone of the server is.  Who knows, you might pick up a server from point a to point b and change the time zone in the process. Do you want that to invalidate the data?  Probably not.  Storing all time as UTC datetimes, or using datetimeoffset, are solutions for that.

Comment: I do plan to have an offset for each datetime stored to account for DST.  Unfortunately, this is in MySQL so none of the datatypes you mentioned would work.  Maybe an offset of minutes stored as integer datatype.  I know it's not the right way to do things, but we're planning to have a separate instance of the database if the server has to move.

Comment: Offsets are not always whole integers.  Consider using either `TIME` or `DECIMAL` type to store the offset.  You would pair this with a `DATETIME` type.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using a `TIMESTAMP` type, which stores data as UTC but converts to/from the server's local time zone every time you read/write from it.  Of course, this might lead to DST issues, but it's worth looking at.

Comment: Can you give examples of non-integer offsets?  I don't see any here unless there are going to be an offsets in seconds in the future. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: India: +5:30.  Australia: +8,+8:45,+9:30,+10,+10:30,+11.  Lots of others.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 0):

It would be a more robust solution to store the times as UTC time as time zone is local to the specific PC that is displaying the data. In your case if you store time plus offset how can you decide which offset to store? Not a workable solution if multiple time zones are involved.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering Mike.  But let's assume that I cannot change the database to store datetime in UTC, is it still possible to add support for timezone?

Comment: On the offset question, since Hawaii does not support DST, I would only have to deal with one offset value for all the current datetimes in the database.  If we are going to be in a location that has DST, I was told that we would have another database with datetimes for that timezone.  And since it would be a fresh database, new datetimes entered would have the correct DST offset.

Comment: And that's easier than converting to utc? I don't see it.

Comment: No it's not easier for sure.  But is it doable?  I'm not avoiding the use of UTC by choice obviously.